# Correctly binding data to a Pie-Chart in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently doing a d3-Project and ran into a problem.

My CSV-File contains data like this:

```
region, number_of_red_cars, number_of_green_cars, number_of_blue_cars, cars_total
A,5,10,5,20
```

I now want to create a pie-chart displaying the share of the diffrent colored cars, but I dont know, which data I have to bind to the pie-chart.

```
d3.csv("details.csv",function(data){



    var filtered = data.filter(function(d) {
    if (d.region== "A")
        return d;

    })



    var g= svg.select("body")
        .data(pie(filtered))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class","arc");


    g.append("path")
        .attr("d",arc)
        .style("fill",function(d){return color (d.data.cars_total)});


    g.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function(d){return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d)+")";})
        .attr("dy", "35.em")
        .text(function(d){return d.data.cars_total;})
        .style("fill","white");
})
```

This wont give me my expected result, since I want a pie chart showing the exact share of every color in context of total cars.

Can anyone help me out? :(

EDIT:
[The Pie Chart should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yqYK.png)

Comment: Can you post your entire code as a snippet? It'd be easier to debug the exact issue.

Comment: Edited the code and added a picture of how the chart should look like :)